# Need help for simle bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ping, nslookup

Can someone help me with the syntax for a simple bash script that trying to write:

```
echo ping -c 1
echo nslookup
```

Basically I want to receive output of one line from the ping and the nslookup information for a domain that I'm checking. Unfortunately I'm unable to get this correctly.

P.s. this is basically the first thing that I'm trying to accomplish in bash.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi after writing and saving script and giving permission to the script 
just go the folder and 
    ./

of else you just can use 
    sh

Comment: After I converted the file to ve unix friendly and I added the script in the /bin folder now it runs only by typing the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the provided information on the matter. I felt little ashamed from the nature of my question so I spent little more time to read. The solution that I found is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $*;do
ping -c 1 $i &
nslookup $i &
done
#
```

'
Once I added the scrit to the /bin folder I used the commands:

```
chmod +x "script name"
dos2unix ""scrit name"
```

so not I'm able to use it only by typing the name of the script.

Comment: Delete ampersand `&` at the end of strings. Use script: `scriptname google.com ya.ru anysite.net` and you will get info about google.com, ya.ru and anysite.net.

Comment: Thank you zombic, after I removed the ampersands the session was over after the execution. I was wondering what was causing that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i would be better if you elaborate your problem, if you want one line output for ping command filter using head

eg 
    ping www.google.com | head -n 1

or if you are thinking of sending one packet of data to the server

```
ping -n 1 www.google.com
```

nslookup www.google.com

and if your are writing Bash Script

#!/bin/bash
   ping -n 1 www.google.com
   nslookup www.google.com

save the file 
give execute permission and run

Please let me know i answered your question

Comment: Thank you, I actually find a solution on the matter. You can check it in the answer that I left. Thank you so much for providing me with that information as well.